# update part of the key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, crud

Q:

If I have a *composite key* combined from 4 fields for example, can I update one of them?

I mean can I execute a statement like this:

```
UPDATE tb 
SET firstCol = '15', secondCol = 'test2' 
WHERE firstCol = '1' AND serial = '2';
```

Given:

- my table name is: `tb`
- my fields are: `firstCol, secondCol, serial`
- my keys are: `firstCol , serial`

Any suggestions? Did I miss some concept?

thanks.

Comment: That's the kind of question that would've been answered by just trying it, which you're eventually going to have to do anyway. Why are you asking?

Comment: i know i can execute it , i mean from logical view ,is that make sense, and if yes does executing sentence like this may cause constrains violation?

Comment: Again, try it. Either it works, or it doesn't. If it doesn't, a perfectly good and reasonable question would be "why not". The reason I asked "why are you asking" is that more often than not, people are not asking the real questions, they are themselves trying to deduce the reason behind the situation they are in, and then they ask about that. Here's an example: Did someone load the shotgun? After a bit of digging, turns out what they really should've asked was "I accidentally shot off my foot, can you help?". Try the SQL, see what happens, take it for a spin.

Comment: And by the way, if you're asking "can I execute it" and then subsequently say "I know I can execute it", again, my prompt would be: Why are you asking then, you seem to know the answer already?

Comment: That's not what you asked, so I'm surprised you downvoted. It could of course make sense, that depends entirely on the context of your application. That may also cause a constraint violation if you have forced referential integrity.

Comment: Take into consideration that when you start updating index keys, you can run into situations where possible page splits resulting from the updates can cause duplicate or skipped rows to occur in SELECT queries. The only isolation mode that would prevent this behavior would be serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may run into problems in updating if you try to make some row into the same values as an existing row.  No matter what you do in an update, the unique constraint will still apply.

If you have related tables and have cascade update turned on, you may have locking issues if many records need to be locked. If you do not have cascade update turned on, you may have issues where a PK cannot be changed until you break those relationships and then put them back after manually changing all the related tables to the new value. This task, either way, should only be done in single user mode during non-peak hours.

Personally, if you need to change the PK, the design of your database is fragile and may cause problems in the future. Especially with a multicolumn key. If this is a one-time, rare change, go ahead and work through the issues. Otherwise, it might be time to decide if having a surrogate key as the PK and a unique index on the multi-columns is a better choice. Multicolumn PKs create much larger indexes not only on the main table but the child tables as well, they can create difficult issues when you need to update one of the columns, and they have performance implications for joins. In general I'm not a fan of them. And defintely not if there are some of those columns that will need updating with any frequency (and by that I mean any large update more than once a year - one or two records OK, but if you are running an update as described more often than once a year, you need to revisit the design in my opinion.).

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can do that, why?
Do you have a problem doing that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. It may be part of the key but it's still a column.

Note: if you have FKs relying on this key then you'll need to consider CASCASE updates. Also, a key update (assuming its clustered) means more work then "normal" because of how non clustered indexes refer to the clustered key